# Prove that $X \nvdash \alpha\to\beta$, $X$ when maximally consistent

Tags: logic

I'm trying to solve a sample exam and I got stuck.

> Let $\alpha, \beta$ be statements and $X$ a set of statement such that $X \cup \{\beta\}$ is maximally consistent.
>
> Given $X \cup \{\beta\} \vdash \alpha $, prove that $X \nvdash \alpha\to\neg\beta$.

I don't know how to start. please help me .. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the deduction theorem, which says: "$X \cup \{ \beta \} \vdash \alpha$ if and only if $X \vdash \beta \rightarrow \alpha$." Suppose for *reductio* that $X \vdash \alpha \rightarrow \neg \beta$ as well. Given $X \cup \{\beta\} \vdash \alpha$, the deduction theorem implies that $X \vdash \beta \rightarrow \alpha$, which you know is equivalent to $X \vdash \neg \alpha \rightarrow \neg\beta$. Hence, $X \vdash (\alpha \vee \neg \alpha) \rightarrow \neg \beta$, and since $\alpha \vee \neg \alpha$ is a tautology, $X \vdash \neg \beta$. But then $X \cup \{\beta\}$ is inconsistent, $\bot$.